# How to make my logging work?

Tags: spring-mvc, logging, spring-security, log4j

I'm tryin to save all authentication events with log4j , I've created this java class :

```
@Component(value = "authListener")
  public class AuthenticationEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent> {

  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationEventListener.class);

   public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent authenticationEvent) {
  if (authenticationEvent instanceof InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent)      {
     return;
  }
  Authentication authentication = authenticationEvent.getAuthentication();
  String auditMessage = "Utilisateur " + authentication.getName() + " login     avec succés: " + authentication.isAuthenticated();
  logger.info(auditMessage);
}

}
```

I'm working with spring Mvc and Spring security, my problem is how to make this log working (configurations) and where to find the logging data ? 
I don't know if my work is correct or not, I need your advices.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what Logger you use (what is in import). Based on that, they are configured in some way.

For example you can use Log4J, you can specify location of log file(s) in property file : [log4j example](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/)

---

As mentioned in example, you create file log4j.properties in src/main/resource and there you can specify the file you want to put output from logs : `log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log4j-application.log`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @libik , I forgot to mention that I'm using log4j, I've updated it.
Is my work correct ? Is there any other configurations to do ?